# Do jQuery get ("tr.sc:show") or similar syntax

Tags: jquery

I would like to write a syntax whose effect is opposite to $(parentID).children("tr.sc:**hidden**").

Do jQuery get ("tr.sc:show") or similar syntax?

Thanks

Comment: $(parentID).children("tr.sc").not(":hidden")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think what you're lookingfor is :visible.  http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/visible

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean [visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(parentID).children("tr.sc:not(:hidden)");
$(parentID).children("tr.sc").not(":hidden");
```